# Poping Up a new window with content in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

Please i need your help, I'm trying to pop up a new window in javascript. the new window would contain the information of the parent window. I added all the content in a div. 
the button that is calling the script is shown below.

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button6"  OnClientClick="PrintElem('#info1');"  CssClass="btn btn-   primary btn-xs" runat="server"  Text="Print Report"/>
```

I have a div can contain all the content i want to display on the new window which is

```
<div id="info1" runat="server">
```

the idea is that i dont want to display the menu of the page. i just want that particular div content to display in the new window. when ever i clicked on the button, its shows an empty page throwing an UNDEFINED exception. thank you for your help.

And here is my script.

```
function PrintElem(elem) {

    Popup($(elem).html());

}

function Popup(Data) {
    var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=1000,width=1200');
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Report Title</title>');
    // mywindow.document.write('<link href="/Content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"   rel="stylesheet"  media="all" /> <link href="/Content/assets/css/plugins/jquery-ui.css"   rel="stylesheet" media="all" /> <link href="/Content/assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet"    media="all" /> <link href="/Content/assets/css/plugins.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" /> <link href="/Content/assets/css/icons.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" /> <link    href="/Content/assets/css/fontawesome/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all"    />');
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body>');
    mywindow.document.write(Data);
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
    mywindow.print();
    //mywindow.close();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: [Media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) are for the task you've at hands.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=1000,width=1200,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no');
```

Edit: The below works for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Popup(Data) {
            var mywindow = window.open('', 'my div', 'height=1000,width=1200');
            mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Report Title</title>');
            // mywindow.document.write('<link href="/Content/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"   rel="stylesheet"  media="all" /> <link href="/Content/assets/css/plugins/jquery-ui.css"   rel="stylesheet" media="all" /> <link href="/Content/assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet"    media="all" /> <link href="/Content/assets/css/plugins.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" /> <link href="/Content/assets/css/icons.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" /> <link    href="/Content/assets/css/fontawesome/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all"    />');
            mywindow.document.write('</head><body>');
            mywindow.document.write(Data);
            mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
            mywindow.print();
            //mywindow.close();
            return true;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="Popup('Hahaha');">Go Popup</button>
</body>
</html>
```